# UWP - apply a multiplied alpha blending between Visuals

Tags: uwp, alphablending, win2d

I have a RelativePanel that contains two children:

- a FrameworkElement A with a ContainerVisual cvA that acts like a
  background
- a RelativePanel B with another ContainerVisual cvB that
  displays some rectangles on the foreground.

To understand better, suppose I have an image as CompositionBrush of a SpriteVisual inside cvA, and I have to super-impose the rectangles (that are SpriteVisuals as well) of cvB.

I want to alpha-blend the colors of the image vs. the rectangles using multiplication (rather than addition), so that those rectangles seems to highlight portions of the image.

How can I achieve this goal?

Note: here you can find a project to reproduce the environment: https://github.com/cghersi/UWPExamples/tree/master/MultiplyAlphaBlending

Comment: I have invited other engineers to participate in this case. If there is any update, I will tell you.

Comment: Thank you @Faywang-MSFT, I will wait for any feedback!